# как преобразовать lan порт в serial?

Tags: администрирование, arduino, serial, lan

суть задачи такая:
подключаем к роутеру ethernet кабель далее через lan2ttl подключаем LoRa, с обратной стороны тоже самое.
Т.е. создаем мост для интернета через LoRa модуль на 433 MHz.
При этом без всяких дополнительных вычислительных устройств типа RaspberryPy.

Comment: Без всяких дополнительных вычислительных устройств не получится, хоть какой то контроллер должен быть который умеет работать с сетью.

Comment: @ГеннадийП А на уровне железа не достаточно будет вычислительной мощности?

Comment: Не понятно что вы хотите от lan2ttl. На алике есть разные адаптеры, подешевле и подороже, соответственно с различным функционалом.

Answer (score 0):

Esp8266 (стоит 1$) потянет эту задачу. Правда он wifi.

На lan микросхему прийдется добавить контроллер вроде ардуины. А готовые lan-serial врятли можно спарить между собой без сервера.